# Configuring eclipseLink with Spring 4.0.2 using Java configuration

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to configure [eclipseLink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) with Spring.

Following is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>roster3</groupId>
    <artifactId>roster3</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>roster3 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.29</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet & jstl -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validation & DB Validation -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>          
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/roster2</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>roster3</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using Java Configuration approach. My `Config.java` is as follow.

```
package com.ecw.roster.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
//import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
//import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration //Marks this class as configuration
@EnableWebMvc
//Specifies which package to scan
@ComponentScan("com.ecw.roster")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
//Enable Spring's annotations
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASEPLATFORM = "databasePlatform";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_GENERATE_DDL = "generateDdl";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_SHOW_SQL = "showSql";

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        System.out.println("UrlBasedViewResolver........");
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }


    @Bean()
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        System.out.println("Driver Name : "  + driverClassName);
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
       transactionManager.setDataSource(getDataSource());
       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ecw.roster.beans" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("roster3");
        DatabasePlatform dp = new MySQLPlatform();        
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());         
        return em;
    }


    private EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter(){
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();      
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform");
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }   


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("In Resouce Handler");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/defaultTheme/");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() { 
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/messages/");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

I am getting following exception.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:376)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:580)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:324)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8079206a.transactionInterceptor(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor(ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8079206a.CGLIB$transactionAdvisor$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8079206a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$26da93e1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8079206a.transactionAdvisor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(TransactionAspectSupport.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 57 more
```

I tried googling it but not able to pin point the issue.

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring versions. You are mixing 2.0.8 and 4.0.2. Never mix versions (spring-jpa belongs to Spring 2.0 not 4.0. replace with spring-orm).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum . That worked. Do you know any good guide on integration on eclipselink in Spring MVC using Java Based configuration ? If yes then please share it. I am stuck at one point

Comment: That is too vague to answer. Create a proper question here on stack overflow with some code and clear description.

Comment: @M.Deinum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942190/configuration-of-eclipselink-spring-mvc-mysql-using-java-configuration-no-x
This is the link with seperate question & code that I tried. Thanks.