# Configuration of eclipselink + Spring MVC + MySql using Java Configuration (No XML configuration)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to integrate `eclipselink JPA` into my Spring Web application.
**Is there any good guide oh how to configure eclipseLink for MySql database in Spring MVC using Java based configuration only?**. No dispatcher-servlet.xml.

I am familiar with Java based Spring configuration. (Using `@Configuration, @EnableWebMvc, @ComponentScan, @EnableTransactionManagement` etc). But not familiar with eclipseLink java based configuration in Spring MVC.

Following is the `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>roster3</groupId>
    <artifactId>roster3</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>roster3 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.29</mysql.connector.version>
        <eclipselink.version>2.5.0</eclipselink.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.5.4</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet & jstl -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validation & DB Validation -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/roster3</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:eclipselink.jar</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This plugin ensures the EclipseLink static weaving -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>au.com.alderaan</groupId>
                <version>1.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>weave</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <logLevel>ALL</logLevel>
                            <!-- <includeProjectClasspath>true</includeProjectClasspath> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                        <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            au.com.alderaan
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0.4,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>weave</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>roster3</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Following is what I tried as of now.

Configuration class `Config.java`

```
package com.ecw.roster.config;

import java.util.Properties;


import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration //Marks this class as configuration
@EnableWebMvc
//Specifies which package to scan
@ComponentScan("com.ecw.roster")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
//Enable Spring's annotations
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASEPLATFORM = "databasePlatform";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_GENERATE_DDL = "generateDdl";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_SHOW_SQL = "showSql";

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernate_dialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernate_show_sql;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packages.to.scan}")
    private String entity_package_to_scan;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        System.out.println("Roster 3 : Initializing UrlBasedViewResolver........");
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){     
        System.out.println("Roster 3 : LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean *************");  
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();       
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());       
       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {          
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();       
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ecw.roster.beans" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("roster3");       
        DatabasePlatform dp = new MySQLPlatform();        
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());       
        return em;
    }   

    private EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter(){
        System.out.println("Roster 3 : EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter initialization ***************");

        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();      
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform");
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    private Properties eclipseLinkProperty(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();       
        properties.put("eclipselink.deploy-on-startup", "true");
        properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-or-extend-tables");
        properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
        properties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "static");
        properties.put("eclipselink.weaving.lazy", "true");
        properties.put("eclipselink.weaving.internal", "true");
        properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "SEVERE");
        properties.put("eclipselink.query-results-cache.type", "WEAK");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing", "JDBC");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size", "1000");
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("In Resouce Handler");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/defaultTheme/");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() { 
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/messages/");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

persistence.xml file for eclipselink:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="roster3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.ecw.roster.beans.Roster</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roster" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mysqladmin" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am able to build & deploy the project but I am getting connection leaks & then my context is stopped by tomcat container.

Please advice me what I am doing wrong with it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning on using Spring Boot or not?

Comment: Nope. I am using Spring with annotation based configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following configuration will enable Spring to use two application contexts (the root context and the web application context) and will configure most of the things you need.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableJpaRepositories("your.jpa.repositories.package")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "gr.xe.payments", excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class), @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE ,value = MvcConfig.class)})
public class ApplicationConfig {


}

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.controller.package", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class))
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesViewResolver = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesViewResolver.setDefinitions(new String[]{"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"});
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        urlBasedViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return urlBasedViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("WEB-INF/i18n/messages");
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}



@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("your.domain.package");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        //This uses JNDI, you could create the data source in any way you want
        try {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            return (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/yourDS");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to lookup datasource", e);
        }
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //use whatever EclipseLink properties you like
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The relevant dependencies are

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>   

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Do we need META-INF/persistence.xml file ? I am novice to both eclipselink & Spring. Not sure if we provide properties from Java Configuration then I guess, META-INF/persistence.xml is not needed.

Comment: No, persistence.xml is not needed. Spring takes care of the registration of the entities using factory.setPackagesToScan()

Comment: Can you share your dependencies, pom.xml ?